# How do I downgrade Xbox 360 dashboard?

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 Elite and I want to downgrade the dashboard version from 2.x to 9199. I tried putting `$SystemUpdate` (from the official $SystemUpdate9199.zip) folder into a FAT32 formatted USB and restarting the console with the USB stick inserted, but it didn't work. What else can I do?

Comment: Out of interest, Why?

Comment: @Diago: It's about JTAG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no easy way of downgrading Xbox 360 Dashboard, since there are physical measures put in place to prevent just that (CPU e-Fuses blow when upgraded to prevent downgrade).

I heard there is a possibility of downgrading certain Dashboard versions by a timing attack, but that requires advanced electronics knowledge (and equipment) and definetly voids your warranty.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you have to do is JTAG your Xbox, then it will work. I'm no expert so double check on YouTube or something. I'm pretty sure, though!

Answer (score -2):

Here's how you do it go to settings then click on storage then press LB RB X LB RB X And keep doing it until you get the dashboard of your likings